# How to index a probability matrix using an argmax-matrix in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Assume that we have defined the following matrices:

```
# shape = (2, 3)
m = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]
    ]
)

# shape = (2, 3, 2)
p = np.array(
    [
        [
            [0.6, 0.4], [0.3, 0.7], [0.8, 0.2]
        ],
        [
             [0.35, 0.65], [0.7, 0.3], [0.1, 0.9]
        ],
    ]
)
```

In this case *p* is a probability matrix, and *m* contains the index of the maximum probability.

How can we index *p* using *m* to get a matrix of shape = *m.shape*, where each element would be the probability corresponding to the index in *m*, such as:

```
result = np.array(
    [
        [0.6, 0.7, 0.8],
        [0.65, 0.7, 0.9]
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.indices`:

```
>>> p[tuple(np.indices(m.shape)) + (m,)]
array([[0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 ],
       [0.65, 0.7 , 0.9 ]])
```

Relatively beautiful two line solution:

```
>>> ii, jj = np.indices(m.shape, sparse=True)   # sparse=True use less memory
>>> p[ii, jj, m]
array([[0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 ],
       [0.65, 0.7 , 0.9 ]])
```

Since `m` ranges from 0 to 1, `np.where` also works:

```
>>> np.where(m.ravel() == 0, *p.reshape(-1, 2).T).reshape(m.shape)
array([[0.6 , 0.7 , 0.8 ],
       [0.65, 0.7 , 0.9 ]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I also found out that one could use "np.take_along_axis(p, m[..., np.newaxis], -1).squeeze()". But which one would you recommend performance-wise?

Comment: @DenisLogvinenko I checked the source code and found that `np.take_along_axis` seems to be doing the same thing as `np.indices` with `sparse=True`. Both are good choices, but `np.indices` seems simpler to me.